# CouchDB Views - OR and AND operators

Tags: view, key, operators, couchdb

I think I'm missing something fundamental about CouchDB views.

Let's say I'm storing cars in a database. I want to get all cars that are blue or red, but NOT green, AND they are Hondas. But this query is dynamic using keys. How do?

Map Function:

```
﻿function(car) {
    emit([car.color, car.make],car);
}
```

I can't find a way to format keys to make anything like this possible. I'm not married to this map function either, I just want to know how someone would handle a request like this on the fly. Do you have to just narrow it down as far as possible in Couch and then do more process with the returned data? Seems like there should be a way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to include the `keys` parameter with your query:

`http://localhost:5984/cars/_design/all-cars/_view/by-color-and-make?keys=[["red","honda"],["blue","honda"]]`

More likely though, you have a search page with a bunch of different characteristics, and the user is picking and choosing values to search by.  They might choose 4 door, all wheel drive, and priced below 10,000.

You won't be able to make views to satisfy all the different combinations.  [couchdb-lucene](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene) is a good option to solve this problem.

And if you use cloudant.com, it's automatically included: https://cloudant.com/for-developers/search/

Comment: Yes I saw some things pointing to lucene. Any good articles on how to get it up and running? The git hub page seems a bit convoluted...